# Titanium -> New Alloy Controller

Tags: macos, controller, titanium, titanium-alloy

Evening all,

I've recently started using Titanium Studio on OSX and creating my first Alloy App,

Ive noticed you can do New -> Alloy Controller

This creates 3 new files,

controller.js

```
/* controller */
```

controller.tss

```
".container": {
    backgroundColor: "white"
}
```

controller.xml

```
<Alloy>
    <View class="container">
    </View>
</Alloy>
```

I'd basically like to modify the templates of the default new files that it creates, or duplicate the Menu option to create a modified version.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

If you look in this [link](https://github.com/appcelerator/alloy/tree/master/test/apps) you should be able to see several sample apps.  These should help you get started.  I have used this and the alloy documentation on their [website](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Alloy_Quick_Start) to get started with Titanium.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, thanks but don't worry this is not what we meant, I needed to edit the Node Module that sets up new controllers, it has 3 template files that it copies into your working directory.